# Does sqlite have an equivalent to MySQL's --execute?

Tags: sqlite

I want to pipe the output of a SQLite query.  With MySQL, I would do `mysql --execute "MYQUERY"`.  How can I achieve the same thing with SQLite?

Answer (score 2):

The optional second argument to the `sqlite3` command is SQL to execute.  So `sqlite3 path/to/my/db "MYQUERY"` does it.